# Jupyter notebook in VS Code - No color for the python code in ipynb-file. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, color-scheme

Code of .ipynb file:

[image: Code of .ipynb]

Python is detected:

[image]

The code has color in jupyter notebook:

[image]

I tried setting up a jupyter notebook in vs code in an anaconda environment. I have tried - Python: Select interpreter and selected my anaconda environment. Made sure python is in the environment: python --version:  Python 3.8.8. Tried clicking on CVE(in the bottom right corner) to change to python (picture 2). The colorization of the code works fine in the interactive window of jupyter notebook (picture 3).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jupyter extension detects your code as CVE instead of Python so Python syntax highlighting is not applied successfully.

Refer to [Jupyter in vscode can't execute syntax highlighting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7917#), the **Dependency Analytics** extension should be the reason. Remove or Disable it then reload window, the question should go away.

Comment: in my case, I was using dot-env extension for nodejs. Apparently, extensions that do stuff with the environment will mess the jupyter extension up.

Answer (score 0):

Disable VS Code's extension "Dependency Analytics" to solve the missing Syntax Highlighting within Jupyter notebook files.

[Disable "Dependency Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE4fh.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE4fh.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31908693)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and when I reloaded one of my extensions (it was Azure Functions in my case) everything was coloured as normal again. Weird...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33039264)